# Force AWS Lambda to use UTC when listing S3 objects using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, boto3

When retrieving a list of objects on AWS Lambda using Python 3.6 and boto3, the objects' `LastModified` attribute is using `'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 17, 1, 51, 31, tzinfo=tzlocal())`.

When I run my program locally, this attribute is using `'LastModified': datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 17, 1, 51, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())`, which is what I want.

Why is this happening? Is there a workaround that will allow me to specify UTC as part of the request? Alternatively, is there a simple way to convert these `datetime`s to UTC after they're returned from S3?

Comment: Interesting... on Amazon Linux 2 it comes back as `tzinfo=tzlocal()`, but on Amazon Linux (v1) it comes back as `tzinfo=tzutc()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil import tz
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal

d_local = datetime(2018, 8, 17, 1, 51, 31, tzinfo=tzlocal())

d_utc = d_local.astimezone(tz.tzutc())
```

The result is that `d_utc` is:

```
datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 16, 15, 51, 31, tzinfo=tzutc())
```